# Bloquear la interaccion del usuario momentaneamente swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Necesito que cuando seo clicke en una opcion de un menu lateral, la interaccion del usuario se deshabilite hasta que se cargue la vista.

Si no lo bloqueo, se carga la vista tantas veces como clicks se haya hecho en el menu.

He probado con esto:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres bloquear interacción con la app hasta que se acabe el movimiento puedes hacerlo mediante:

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

No te lo recomiendo pero es una opción y la puedes llamar desde donde quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Yp utilizo esa función cuando llamo a un menú pero lo convino con un activity indicator, sin embargo por que no intentas bloquear la interacción del propio elemento para que no puedan dar click en el y activarlo de nuevo cuando termine la carga?

Mira esto

touch.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

o incluso de la propia vista contenedora.